# Table Row & Column Search Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know much about Java Script or Jquery, but I am trying to work out how I can get a Search Filter to work with this code..

```
       <div id="table-container">
<table id="maintable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
<thead>
  <tr><!-- FIX: Needed to wrap it in a row -->
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Number</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Original Title</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Translated Title</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Languages</th>
  <th width="10%" class="blk" nowrap>Movie Length</th>
  <th width="10%" class="blk" nowrap>Year</th>
  <th width="10%" class="blk" nowrap>Resolution</th>
  <th width="10%" class="blk" nowrap>Rating</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>IMDB MOVIE URL</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>$$LABEL_CATEGORY</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
$$ITEM_BEGIN
<tr><!-- FIX: Needed to wrap it in a row -->
<td rowspan="2" class="lgt" style="height:120px;"><strong>$$ITEM_NUMBER&nbsp;$$ITEM_APPR10<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;$$ITEM_PICTURE&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;"><strong>$$ITEM_ORIGINALTITLE&nbsp;</strong></td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">$$ITEM_TRANSLATEDTITLE&nbsp;</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">$$ITEM_LANGUAGES&nbsp;</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">$$ITEM_LENGTH&nbsp;</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">&nbsp;$$ITEM_YEAR&nbsp;</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">$$ITEM_RESOLUTION&nbsp;</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">$$ITEM_RATING&nbsp;</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;"><a href="$$ITEM_URL" target="_blank">$$ITEM_ORIGINALTITLE</a></td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">$$ITEM_CATEGORY&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
<td height="14%" colspan="9" class="myButton">CLICK ME FOR MORE INFORMATION OR CLICK ME FOR LESS</td>
</tr>
<tbody class="myContent" style="display:none;">
<tr>
<td colspan="10"class="lgt"><strong><br>$$LABEL_ACTORS&nbsp;</strong><br>$$ITEM_ACTORS<br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="10"class="lgt"><strong><br>$$LABEL_DESCRIPTION&nbsp;</strong><br>$$ITEM_DESCRIPTIONS<br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="10"class="lgt"><strong><br>$$LABEL_COMMENTS&nbsp;</strong><br>$$ITEM_COMMENTS<br></td>
</tr class="data"><!-- FIX: close row -->
</tbody>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="20" class="blk"></td>
</tr>
$$ITEM_END
</table>
```

This Link http://jsfiddle.net/urf6P/3/ is a bit of an example of what I believe could work, but i'm not sure if it will do exactly what I want.
The above code is a Template used it a Movie Catalog Program, and it generates to HTML.

The problem I get when trying any filters is when it gets to this part:

```
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="14%" colspan="9" class="myButton">CLICK ME FOR MORE INFORMATION OR CLICK ME FOR LESS</td>
```

The  stops it, and doesn't make the rest disappear.

This link www.vijayjoshi.org/examples/filterTable.html is another one I have tried, but I still get issues with bring up the whole section. 
What happens if the "myButton" appears on the other movies that aren't for that specific name.

Sorry for blabbing, just trying to make sure I touch base with everything as trying to show other codes, I don't know if it will work..

Here is a tester page I have been playing around with to get it to work.. I know my html isn't organised or great, but I will admit I am no pro.. http://www.mrtrent.altervista.org/Movie_List.html

Thanks in advanced for any help provided. And if anyone has suggestions to help me improve on my site please do let me know, but if you want to just laugh, don't comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Change Function with Keyup .

```
$(function() {    
    $('#filter1').change(function() { 
        $("#table td.col1:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().show();
        $("#table td.col1:not(:contains('" + $(this).val() + "'))").parent().hide();
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urf6P/577/)

Comment: I have tried this Code, I just seem to have issues, such as, all of it disappearing, rather then everything but what was typed. Also it was case sensitive, and had to be the full word, which is really convenient.. I have a feeling I may need to use DIVs to make it really work, but I have no clue how to use them either.. This is a pretty tough challenge for me..